# Does gevent library have some method for continue join spawn?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent, coroutine

I have a server connect to a redis running on pub/sub model.
The pubsub object listenning certain channel waitting for messages.
The users continue come and go, which means some pubsub object join the process to listening and some of them left and delete the pubsub object.

I find gevent can use like:

```
threads = [thread1, thread2, thread3]
gevent.joinall(threads)
```

for my case the threads (actually I do not want it waiting for whole thread, I want to use coroutine replace thread waiting here) is dynamic, does gevent has ability to get the thread join later on? I mean like:

```
threads=[thread1]
g=gevent.joinall(threads)
...
...
```

(another user comming)

```
g.join(thread2)
...
```

(another user comming)

```
g.join(thread3)
...
```

Is there some library have similar ability?